# python unit test - how to test function local JSON object has correct key value pairs?

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, unittest2

I'm new to Python and unit testing as I just started looking into it this morning. I have a object that has a number of key/pair values as well as one of those key/pairs being another object.

ie.

```
my_program.py

    def my_function(self):
        my_obj = {
            "someKey": 1234-5678,
            "locationId": self.location_id,
            "environment": self.environment_name,
            "metaData" : {
                "log_id": self.last_log_id,
                "satisfied": False 
            }
        }


tests_my_program.py

import unittest2
import mock

    def test_should_check__my_function__payload_obj_is_set(self):
        #code here to test the variable has all of those key/pair values
```

How do I write a unit test to ensure that this object always has these key/pair values (someKey, locationId, etc.) ? **My tests are in a separate python file (test_my_program.py) so would i need to mock my_obj to the test function?**

This variable is local to a function so it's not global.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
import unittest
from my_program import my_obj

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_the_thing(self):
        self.assertEqual(my_obj['key1']['key2'], 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

if you just want to know if the value is true use `self.assertTrue(my_obj['key1']['key2'])` or `self.assertFalse`

I'm not sure what you mean by "mock my_obj" but you can just import it from the other module to test it. Why mock when you can use the real thing?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in the original. my_obj is local to a function and not a global variable.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the function you're trying to test. Are you saying you want to run a test within a function? You can always do assertions wherever you want. by just using the `assert` keyword like `assert 3 == 4` will raise an `AssertionError`.

Comment: This is a poor solution. For example if `'key1'` is missing exception will be raised instead triggering assertion.

Comment: @MarekR In that case the test is still failing, so it accomplishes the same goal. If you're worried about the type of exception you could add `assert 'key1' in my_obj` before the other line.